# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, servicepacks

I have installed the German version of Visual Studio 2010 Professional (got it per [Microsoft DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/)). When I'm trying to install the [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/de-de/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5), I get the following message from the installer:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 kann nicht installiert werden, da es vom aktuellen Zustand dieses Computers nicht unterstützt wird. Anweisungen zum Beheben des Problems finden Sie in der Infodatei auf der Microsoft Download Center-Website.

An English translation is:

> Can't install SP1, as the actual state of the Computer is not supported.

Does anybody has a similar problem and a solution? My operating system is Windows 7 64-Bit (German Edition).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Visual Studio 2010 Premium, also on a German Windows 7 64 bit. After several hours I managed to install the Service Pack 1.

The *problem* is that the setup requires Visual Studio Tools for Office to be installed on x64 machines. So customize your Visual Studio 2010 Installation via the control panel (add/remove programs) and add the feature "Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64)". After adding this feature, you will be able to start the SP1 Setup.

Comment: Thanks, after installing the `Office Developer Tools` it work's :)

Comment: Glad I could help. According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/a869f387-3bee-4c93-bc2c-df59cfeb858d/ the problem is not 64 bit-specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fixed my installation after 3h of researching of fix.

Comment: After adding Microsoft Office Developer Tools, I still got the error "13EC" with windows update. Downloading the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack from the Microsoft Download Center solved the issue, the installation finished successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 and are trying to install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (regardless of whether via Windows Update, Online installer or Offline Standalone SP1 Installer) it needs Office Tools for Visual Studio 2010. However only the Runtime MSI Packages (vstodtr40_x86.msi or stodt40r_x64.msi) are available for download. You actually need the installer vstodt40_x64.msi (64-Bit) or vstodt40_x86.msi (32-Bit). On commercial versions of Visual Studio 2010 these are included in the Folder \WCU\VSTO.

After you install the Office Tools as above you will be able to install the Service Pack. If you try with just the runtime it will fail. I know because I tested it.

Comment: ". . . have Visual Studio 2010 and trying to Update to Visual Studio 2010"??  Did you mean something else here?

Comment: @Peter is this a better/different solution to the one by @Christian?

Comment: For me, I downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 sp1 ISO file and found the vstodt40_x64.msi file there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

First you have to download **Visual Studio 2010 Tools for the Office System 4.0 Runtime Service Pack 1**.

After you install it successfully, download **Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1**.

*Both packs are located with the same link:*
(https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010%20service%20pack%201)