# Visual C# 2010 Express SP1 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, servicepacks

I got an error 13EC when installing SP1 for MSVS. This problem is described here [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296830/microsoft-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-installation/)
But how can I add the feature "Microsoft Office Developer Tools" in Visual C# 2010 Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran in to this error 13EC while installing the MS Visual Studio 2012 SP 1 through Windows Update. I'm running VS 2010 Ultimate - ENU and had removed the original installation source. (Don't know whether that matters)

As [these](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/trying-to-install-the-service-pack-1-for-visual/d9ef0c29-9bbd-40db-bf27-3795d785b07d?msgId=06f4d1d9-4bf2-48c2-aa5c-ec9ba355cf8b) [threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/4ae02167-4418-491c-8411-82fa81b118bd) suggest, low disk space might be the problem. The first thread mentions the limit to be 5.5GB, which I can't comment on, but increasing my HD free space from 3.7GB to >10GB did to fix the problem. I had three back-to-back failed installs (with intermediate restarts) but after increasing the free disk space it finished successfully on the fourth try, although it did take an incredibly long time to finish. (the progress bar's last 5% or so took up more than 90% of the time)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you get the list of features which will be installed, where you can add remove features, before the installation starts? You should find `Microsft Office Developer Tools` in the list. So, just try reinstalling and make sure you enable that feature.

Also, one of the answers in the link you provided has

> So customize your Visual Studio 2010
>   Installation via the control panel (add/remove programs) and add the
>   feature "Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64)". After adding this
>   feature, you will be able to start the SP1 Setup.

Comment: But the problem lies in the fact that the tools are not available for express editions.